# Get Base Url in JS Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, layout, template

```
<reference name="head">
<block type="fabric_tool/tool" name="js" template="fabric/tool/global.phtml"/>

<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><file>js/fabric/tool/men_default.js</file></action>
</reference>
```

in global.phtml file, I have code like

```
<script>
     var BASE_URL='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>';
</script>
```

in **men_default.js**, I have taken `BASE_URL`. But When application is loaded, JS is appended before **global.phtml** is appended. so that, I can not access `BASE_URL` variable in **men_default.js**. So What do I have to do? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. Because..

> child blocks which are included inside `head` block will get only rendered after rendering/including js and css which are added in `head` block, irrespective of the point of inclusion in the layout update xml.

**Proof :** `head` block stands for `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` and by default it uses `page/html/head.phtml` file. Inside that file, you can see this

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

From the above code, it is obvious that, blocks included in `head` section will get rendered "later".

So you can probably go with below method. It may work in your case.

***You need to add `menu_default.js` inside the phtml file itself.***

That is your layout update xml should only contain the phtml file.

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="fabric_tool/tool" name="js" template="fabric/tool/global.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Here you need to make sure the above `js` block type is actually valid and does define inside magento block section.

Next update your `global.phtml` file with this content.

```
<script>
     var BASE_URL='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/fabric/tool/men_default.js');?>"></script>
```

This way javascript variable `BASE_URL` is now defined before `menu_default.js` and hence you can get the value inside that file.

Comment: That is a good idea. But When I do as you said, It shows some errors like **Invalid base url type**

Comment: there was an error in the phtml code. I updated it. Use the updated code again

Comment: It is ok.. I found another way to get skin url. I am using this **<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/fabric/tool/variables.js');?>**. Anyway thank you to lead me to get solution.

Comment: ya it will also work, since it is using inside a phtml file. I will update my code with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the code which is trying to access BASE_URL inside a dom:loaded function

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    console.log(BASE_URL);
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907702/document-observedomloaded-function

If you're using jQuery you could use

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log(BASE_URL);
});
```

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Here, I cant put this.. because so many functions that are in men_default.js using BASE_URL variable. So, the functions would not wait until document ready.

Comment: Really the code that's executing should be waiting for the DOM to be fully loaded anyway. When/where are these functions called? On the initial load or view users actions?

Comment: On the initial load Some functions will be called, And user also can call those functions by clicking controls..